Issue when trying to upload old Flutter project to Play Store
I have a Flutter application using version 2.10.1. I updated some libraries in this project, and now, when I try to upload the application to the Play Store, I am getting the following error:
"Update your com.google.android.play:core:1.9.1 Maven dependency to an Android 14 compatible version! Your current com.google.android.play:core:1.9.1 library is incompatible with targetSdkVersion 34 (Android 14), which introduces a backward-incompatible change to broadcast receivers. As a reminder, from 31 August 2024, Google Play requires all new app releases to target Android 14. Update to the latest library version dependency to avoid app crashes."
I can see in the .pubCache folder that the amplify_auth_cognito library is using amplify_core, which in turn is using com.google.android.play:core:1.9.1.
Is there any solution to this so that I can upload the application to the Play Store without any errors?
I have changed amplifyframework:Core Maven dependancy.But it is not working for me.enter image description here

You can check out this link for reference:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/11926878?hl=en

you should update app to newest,

For latest version you can check : https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore

you should update yourtargetSdk in build.gradle
